# Há problema de utilizar duas versões diferentes de bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, apache-cordova

Boas eu tenho um problema, tenho um projecto em cordova que estava a utilizar o bootstrap 3.3.7 porem neste muito tou a passar tudo para o bootstrap 4.0.0, porem pensei em deixar os 2 no projecto pois cada um tem diferentes css. Gostaria de saber se existe algum problema quanto a isso !

Comment: Não me parece uma boa ideia, com certeza vão haver conflitos

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, Então na sua opinião é um erro?

Comment: Vou fazer uma resposta pra te mostrar o que pode ocorrer

Comment: Aqui tem o Guia oficial para fazer a Migração https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/ outro ponto bem básicão é que o Grid de uma versão é bem diferente do da outra! Inclusive os "Break Point" responsivos têm medidas diferentes de uma para o outro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na maioria das situações, o que vai ocorrer é o elemento pegar o estilo da  versão do `Bootstrap` que foi incluída por ultimo, como nos 2 exemplos a baixo:

**Versão 4**

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Botão Bootstrap 4</button>
```

**Versão 3**

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Botão com Bootstrap 3</button>
```

Agora, em alguns elementos, pode haver conflito, como no exemplo abaixo, onde a seta pra baixo do dropdown acaba ficando fora de posição usando um `.btn-group` e `.dropdown`:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown com conflito
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Conclusão**
Além de conflitos de estilo, podem haver conflitos entre os **JS** das duas versões, a não ser que você divida sua aplicação em dois blocos diferentes pra cada versão do `Bootstrap` não aho que seja uma boa ideia manter as duas no mesmo projeto, recomendo migração da versão antiga para a **v4**, ou usar a **v3** nessa nova parte.

**OBS:**

Teste feito no Chrome Win 10.

Comment: Muito bem explicado muito obrigado! @

Comment: @Humbertovieira se resolveu o seu problema podia clicar no 'check' verde ali no canto pra aceitar a resposta, assim outros usuários vão saber que essa duvida foi solucionada ;D